# JavaScript atob operation using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, encryption

I would like to know if it is possible to decrypt the JavaScript encrypted text (which is encrypted using JavaScript's btoa function), using PHP.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Have a look at [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

JavaScripts `btoa()` just encodes a string using [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The PHP functions for that are [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: @Sam, what's the answer then?

Answer (score 6):

When I use window.btoa(String) [to encode (not encrypt)](https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/) text and send it over to the server side via AJAX, I find that the client-server exchange has resulted in plus signs ('+'), in the encoded text, being replaced by spaces (' ').

To get the text back to proper encoding in PHP, I've had to use string transform like so:

```
$clean = strtr( $_POST['ajax-text'], ' ', '+');
$ascii = base64_decode( $clean );
```

Comment: Sounds like you've sent the encoded text in the query string of a URL. You should encode it using `encodeURIComponent` before inserting it.