# UTF-8 Passing Data from Javascript to PHP with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having issues with formulating the right combination for an identical match of input and output from Javascript to PHP and then back to Javascript

Javascript Encode: (textarea=input1) => outputs to (textarea=input2)
`btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('.input1').value)));`

PHP Decode: (textarea=input2) => outputs to (textarea=input3)
`htmlspecialchars(SQLite3::escapeString(base64_decode($_POST['input2'])));`

PHP Encode: (textarea=input3) => outputs to (textarea=input4) 
`base64_encode(htmlspecialchars(urldecode(($d['data']))));`

Javascript Decode: (textarea=input4) => outputs to (textarea=input5) 
`decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(document.querySelector('.input4').value)));`

But they do not match, I use https://text-compare.com/ to compare, it outputs in input and shows `&amp;quot;` and it also Deletes all `+` signs

How do I get a both input and output to match identically?

Comment: Why such complication? Why do you need URI encoding, Base64 and HTML escaping all at the same time?

Comment: It is unclear from this how exactly you pass that data, but as for strictly the format of data to use, i think you'd have more luck with json. Which would be `json_encode` and `json_decode` in PHP, and `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` in Javascript. Optionally you can still base64 that if your goal is to hide it. But this will be more reliable than all the escaping you're currently doing. Sidenote, maybe it's the `ENT_QUOTES` parameter you were missing on the PHP side.

Comment: I'm passing it through Ajax and I get Latin1 out of range and it is being passed in json, its the encoding that is the issue

Comment: Oh, i see what you're saying.. Well in that case your solution is `mb_convert_encoding` in PHP.

Comment: in which part do I place that?

Comment: after leaving it for 4 month, I've done it, the answer was in my question all along and didn't realise, if it deletes all the +, I used $clean = strtr($_POST["x"], ' ', '+'); to place the + signs back and it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626535/javascript-atob-operation-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I used, do correct me if I'm wrong/quicker way, it encodes, passes through ajax to php, decodes, encodes, passes back through ajax to js response, then final decode, the match from input to output was identical even with emojis

I'm posting the method below to help anyone in the same situation as I was

```
Method was 
  JS Encode: url > btoa
  PHP Clean: ' ' > '+'
  PHP Decode: json > base64 > url
  PHP Encode: url > base64 > json
  JS Decode: json > atob > url

JS Page:
  Encode to pass through AJAX to PHP :
    //create the json objects
    var obj = {"data":{}};
    //add data
    obj['data'][0] = window.btoa(encodeURIComponent((data)));
  Decode from PHP through AJax
    //parse json
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    //decode
    var x = (decodeURIComponent(window.atob(json.data[0])));
  Ajax Header: Post
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

PHP Page:
  Decode:
    //clean post
    $clean = strtr($_POST["x"], ' ', '+');
    //decode json
    $obj = json_decode($clean, true);
    //decode javascript post
    $decode['data']['0']  = rawurldecode(base64_decode($obj['data'][0]));
  Encode:
    //encode javascript post
    $encode['data']['0']  = base64_encode(rawurlencode($decode['data'][0]));
    //encode json
    echo json_encode($encode);
```

The clean of the post I got from this page [JavaScript atob operation using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626535/javascript-atob-operation-using-php)

The rawurl I got from this page [PHP equivalent for javascript escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534674/php-equivalent-for-javascript-escape-unescape/18468671)